# How can i split ArrayList<String> to ArrayList<Character> in java?

Tags: java, string, arraylist, split, char

I have ArrayList of type String like ArrayList words = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("hello","Monjed","Nidal"));
and i want to split this arraylist to type character like "h","e","l","l"....

Comment: Check this post https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-a-string-to-a-list-of-characters-in-java/

Comment: ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("hello","Monjed","Nidal"));
char[] charArray = String.join("", words).toCharArray();

Answer (score 1):

You can use streams to do this. Your question is a little unclear, do you want a list of char lists or a single list with all the chars in it?

List of lists:

```
words.stream().map(word -> Arrays.asList(word.toCharArray())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Single list of chars:

```
words.stream().flatMap(word -> Stream.of(word.toCharArray())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using streams.

```java
List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList("Hello", "World");
List<Character> charList = new ArrayList<>();
stringList.forEach(item ->
   charList.addAll(item.chars().mapToObj(e -> (char) e).toList())
);
```

Output will be: `[H, e, l, l, o, W, o, r, l, d]`